# How to compare different Azure VMs for performance testing

Tags: performance-testing

**Description:**

In our Performance Test environment, we have used a combination of following Azure VMs:
D4s_v3, Standard F8s , D32s_v3.
But our Production environment has a different set of high performant VMs like Standard_DS5_v2.

With the current VMs available in Performance Test environment, I want to carry out test runs and then use these results to see if Production env. can perform properly or not.

To compare different VM types, I tried using this [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/compute-benchmark-scores#dsv2---memory-optimized--premium-storage) as a reference.

**Query:**

My question is, will it be correct to use the average score as a scaling factor to extrapolate the results for production environment? If not, what other scaling factor can I use to extrapolate the results.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extrapolate the test results and cannot predict what would be system performance in production by running a test against a scaled down environment.

What you can do is:

1. Run an [integration test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) to ensure that the system is doing what it is supposed to be doing
2. Run a [load test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) to see if the scaled down system can support anticipated number of users
3. Run a [stress test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing) to identify the first bottleneck, it might be the case it is not connected with lack of resources like CPU or RAM or whatever
4. Run a [soak test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Soak_testing) to identify possible [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

Comment: I would advise to first perform a stress test; identify bottlenecks and finetune configuration. Then do a load test in the newly optimized environment to validate performance requirements. Other than that, agree.